# How in neovim to use auto-imports in TS files with default absolute paths, not relative ones?

Tags: neovim

WebStorm has a setting to make auto-imports absolute.

[image]

How to do the same in **Neovim**? By default, auto-imports in Neovim are relative:

```
import { Component } from '../Component'
```

And I need to use the paths from `tsconfig.json`. I use **Astrovim**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a plugin for eslint https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-no-relative-import-paths

```json
{
  "plugins": ["no-relative-import-paths"],
  "rules": {
    "no-relative-import-paths/no-relative-import-paths": [
      "error",
      { "allowSameFolder": true, "rootDir": "src", "prefix": "" }
    ]
  }
}
```